# jQueryUI - handling 'click'\'select' event of an already selected tab

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a jQueryUI tabs object, and i want to handle the event of a tab being clicked, when is already selected.
using:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function (event, ui) {
        onSelected();
    }
});
```

I'm able to handle the event when the tab is first clicked (selected), but when i click it again - the handler isn't called.
is there any solution for that?

---

**If not** - another option that will suit my needs is the following:
define the tabs as collapsible, and collapse them by script (and not by user click).
i define the tabs object as:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    collapsible: true
});
```

but when i try to simulate a click using:

```
$("#tabs").tabs("select", 0);
```

or

```
$("#tab-link-0").trigger('click');
```

nothing happens.

I need to point out that the tabs are added dynamically, using:

```
$("#tabs").tabs("add", "#tab-link-0", "title 0");
```

any ideas\suggestions for any of the cases?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experimented a bit and found out that you can prevent the collapse of a tab by calling `event.preventDefault()` in the `select` handler. You obviously only want to do this when the `select` handler is fired on your currently-selected tab (to prevent collapsing the tab), or you'll never be able to switch the tab. This is worth testing, due to the call to `preventDefault()` on the jQuery event, but it appears to give you the behavior you want, at least in Chrome:

```
var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
   collapsible: true,
   select: function(event, ui) {
      if (tabs.tabs('option', 'selected') === ui.index) {
         // Prevent the tab from collapsing if the event fired on the 
         // currently-selected tab
         event.preventDefault();
      }
      onSelected();
   }
});
```